# convert text field to number

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

I have a data extension with a text field that contains numbers like 25.00, 130.00.

I'm trying to convert that to a number field so I can write a condition number greater then but because its a text field doesn't work

I looked for other topics related and tried cast, convert, replace but nothing seems to work

```
SELECT CAST(CAST (Address_ID AS NUMERIC(19,4)) AS INT) AS Address_ID FROM table_1 

SELECT CONVERT(INT,Address_ID) FORM table_1 

SELECT REPLACE(Field1,',','.') as 'Field1' FROM data_extension 

SELECT FLOOR(REPLACE(FIELD1,',','.')) as 'Field1' FROM [data_extension]
```

Any other ideas?

Comment: Can you share your specific error? At what point in the process is this failing?

Comment: just found the error, the solution is this SELECT REPLACE(Field1,',','.') as 'Field1' FROM data_extension Instead of the dot I had to write the exact decimal number that I set up the data extension with

Comment: I would go ahead and add this as the answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to use `SELECT REPLACE(Field1,',','.') as 'Field1' FROM data_extension` and Instead of the dot I had to write the exact decimal number that I set up the data extension with. So if your data type is 18,2 the query should look like this

`SELECT REPLACE(Field1,',','2') as 'Field1' FROM data_extension`